# What does Derrr mean

Tags: meaning

I have seen this word DERRR with 3 "R's" and I looked up for the definition on many website but i haven't found like the exact definition 
Could you help me and give some examples to understand 
Thank you

Comment: Please provide a complete sentence or example. It's likely [_der_](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=der) (Urban Dictionary).

Comment: As an acronym it may stand for different terms: http://www.acronymfinder.com/DERR.html

Comment: I got this definition from urban dictionary.com. it seems so straight forward and simple that I dint want to give it as an answer. Coming to the word, "derrr"
something you say when someone is being stupid
"derrr what an idiot." But I am not sure if it has any other meaning other than this. And yes. I do accept that as an acronym it can stand for many things. I haven't researched into that. But OP hasn't mentioned whether he wants it as acronym or a word as such.

Comment: @VanpramP is correct. It's not used much anymore, but at one time it was a vernacular expletive addressed to an idiot. See [**this link.**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=derrr)

Comment: People still say it, although it's morphed a bit into *derp* and derived forms like *derpy*.  It's more commonly spelled *durr*.

Answer (score 1):

In English it's not uncommon to take a word and repeat a particular letter from that word multiple times in order to simulate how it would sound if spoken.  The intent is to add emphasis to the word, frequently for satirical effect.  For example, Steve Martin's signature phrase from back when he did stand-up comedy:

> [Well excuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuse me!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gi9zFRBCIM)

Obviously "excuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuse" is not a real word.  The word is "excuse", but Martin would elongate the sound of the word to make it funny.

(Side note:  I don't know why it was funny.  As in any language, it's not just what many comedians *say* that's funny, but rather the overall effect from the combination of word choice, timing, body language, and context.)

"Derr" is a slang term used to imply the listener is or has done something idiotic.  "DERRRRR!" is same word, emphasized for satirical effect.  The caps and the exclamation point add to this.  You don't often see this in writing, except perhaps with informal communication like texts, email, personal notes, etc. or as dialogue in a novel.